# How to get the name of the uri_path that Coap's client is writing to in Resource class?

Tags: python, class, oop, coap

I have defined my resource class as following;

```
class Humidity(resource.Resource):
    async def render_post(self, request):
        payload = request.payload.decode("ascii")
        print("Received message: ", payload, "from")
        return #aiocoap.Message(code=CHANGED, payload=b"ACK")
```

And this is the object instantiation;

```
root.add_resource(('humidity_sensor1_indus',), Humidity())
```

I would like to print the name of the uri_path ('humidity_sensor1_indus' in this case) where I am printing the received message.

So far I have tried the following but it does not work;

```
`class Humidity(resource.Resource):
    async def render_post(self, request):
        payload = request.payload.decode("ascii")
        print("Received message: ", payload, "from", request.uri_path)
        return #aiocoap.Message(code=CHANGED, payload=b"ACK")`
```

Let me know what you would do.

Answer (score 0):

The way you *should* be able to obtain the request's original URI is through `request.get_request_uri()`. (The information about the path alone would be in `request.opt.uri_path`, but in the course of path routing these items are removed).

However, due to a [bug in aiocoap](https://github.com/chrysn/aiocoap/issues/306), the output of `.get_request_uri()` is wrong; it should be fixed in the next version (0.4.6).

---

By the way, you should rarely need that information (which is why that error was only discovered when answering your question): A handler should work the same no matter where it is instantiated. The only reason I've found so far for using the request path inside a handler is when working with data formats that do not have functioning relative URI references (eg. RFC6690 Link Format).